# jquery slider tooltip does not update on textbox change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a jquery slider control with a tooltip. user can either slide to change value which adjusts the tooltip, or the user can enter the value in the textbox and the slider and tooltip should adjust value in the textbox.

see attached jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k2sarah/caUku/2/.

```
<div id='slider'></div>
<div id='slider2'></div>
<input id='t1' type='text' />       


var initialValue = 2012;

var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
    var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
    var target = ui.handle || $('.ui-slider-handle');                                     
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue +
         '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';   
   $(target).html(tooltip);


 }

    $('#t1').change(function () {
    var value = $('input[id$=t1]').val();
    $("#slider").slider("value", parseInt(value));
                    sliderTooltip;
    });

    $("#slider").slider({
    value: initialValue,
    min: 1955,
    max: 2015,
    step: 1,
    create: sliderTooltip,
    slide: sliderTooltip


 });

    var sliderTooltip1 = function(event, ui) {
        var curValue1 = ui.value || initialValue;
         var target = ui.handle || $('.ui-slider-handle');
        var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue1 +  
        '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>'; $(target).html(tooltip);
    }

    $("#slider2").slider({
        value: initialValue,
        min: 1955,
        max: 2015,
        step: 1,
        create: sliderTooltip1,
        slide: sliderTooltip1
    });
```

following code adjusts the value of slider but not cause tooltip value to be reflected to current slider value.

```
$('#t1').change(function () {
var value = $('input[id$=t1]').val();
$("#slider").slider("value", parseInt(value));
                sliderTooltip;
});
```

any help would be appreciated.

thks
ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many errors in your fiddle, should be:

```
$('#t1').change(function () {
    var value = $('input#t1').val();
    $("#slider1").slider("option", "value", parseInt(value, 10));
    sliderTooltip();
});
```

EDIT:
added `change` event to update handle value as well:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
    $(".tooltip-inner", this).html(ui.value);  /*thanks rusIn */
```

and you can add following to `slide:` to reflect changes in the input field also:

```
$('#t1').val(ui.value);
```

see working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pl71/bWMne/3/)

Comment: Thks....re working fiddle, when i change textbox, slider position changes, but tooltip does not reflect changed values

Comment: @2428475 see EDIT in answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/mJnKL/)

this will trigger slider's change event:

```
$('#t1').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(".slider").slider("value", parseInt(value));
    });
```

Now we have to listen to the change event inside the slider :

```
 change: function (event, ui) {
            $(".tooltip-inner").html(ui.value);
        }
```

And the entire slider now looks like this(as you can see tooltip is being setup only once on create ):

```
$(".slider").slider({
        value: initialValue,
        min: 1955,
        max: 2015,
        step: 1,
        create: sliderTooltip,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $(".tooltip-inner").html(ui.value);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            $(".tooltip-inner").html(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke your function, try changing:

```
sliderTooltip;
```

to:

```
sliderTooltip();
```